# Seating arrangements of five people with restrictions

Tags: permutations, combinations

Alice refuses to sit next to either Bob or Carla. Derek refuses to sit next to Eric. How many ways are there for the five of them to sit in a row of 5 chairs under these conditions?

$\textbf{(A)}\ 12\qquad\textbf{(B)}\ 16\qquad\textbf{(C)}\ 28\qquad\textbf{(D)}\ 32\qquad\textbf{(E)}\ 40$

Answer is $28$.

I don't know how to get this answer?  Please help in details.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

Case 1 -

If Alice is not at extreme ends. Then Derek and Eric sit on her left and right.

Case 2 -

If Alice is at extreme end Either Eric or Derek sits on her one side.

Taking both above cases place remaining two in remaining positions. But in case 2 don't place Eric and Derek together.